# Is there a way to tell accessibility validation software to ignore content in an iframe that's not mine?

Tags: iframe, web, accessibility

I have cross domain iframe which is missing some of the accessibility attributes. Now issue is since I do not have access to that cross domain iframe and how it was created. Is there a way I can say in my HTML document to let validation tools (eg Worldspace FireEyes) know to ignore that iframe for any accessibility issues - so that my page doesn't get flagged with errors due to that other content?

I am trying to find any tag which will complete ignore content inside it so that web accessibility validator software will ignore it completely.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is the iframe itself missing stuff or is the page you are grabbing as a source missing stuff? Also please identify the errors.

Comment: iframe is missing stuff not page. Since it is cross domain iframe so there is no way i can manipulate the content

Comment: Are you actually trying to disable any accessibility support that may be present in the iframe content, or just tell validators to ignore it since its not your own content? (I'm not sure if either of these is possible - but they are two very different things so worth clarifying anyhow.)

Comment: Paul, Ok can you expand on what you mean by "missing stuff." My same thought Brendan, and neither is possible. I need to know what he is really asking to provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi @BrendanMcK "accessibility support that may be present in the iframe content" is not possible since content is cross domain an I cannot tell vendor to change their code support web accessibility ..So only option left is "validators to ignore it since its not your own content" ---BTW i am using Worldspace FireEyes ...

Comment: @RyanB sorry for the confusion and incomplete question . Missing attribute are name,title ...I am just trying find a close solution...

Comment: Got it - Wordspace FireEyes is a validation tool (appears to work against the live DOM vs a initial tree like traditional validation tools use). I don't think there's anything you can do here; there's no standard markup that you can use as a hint to a validation tool that some content is not your content; it will just check everything it's told do. The best you can do is let the people using the tool against your page know that you've validated *your* portion of the page, and that any loaded content is not your responsibility.

Comment: This would be an interesting question to ask the FireEyes guys as a possible feature request, perhaps. Or perhaps FireEyes should be aware that errors found in cross-site iframes should be clearly marked as belonging to *that* site, not the host page.

Comment: @BrendanMcK agree with you(cross-site iframes should be clearly marked as belonging to that site, not the host page) ..mostly we have our own set of rules(deployed to FireEyes server) validating through company account ...and those rules are written by accessibility team and they just will open any accessibility bug if it give error.  BTW thanks a ton for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ["Partial page analysis with scope definitions"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHuAMlrxepg) (YouTube video). Inside that video the presenter defines a specific section of the site as a "scope". He then is able to

1. let Worldspace FireEyes only analyze that defined scopae
2. analyze the whole document **except for the defined scopes** (he mentions it when selecting the scope)

The second option sounds like it could help you.

If you instead try to mark up your site so that external users of Worldspace FireEyes get a "green bar", I don't think that this is possible. You present that content to your users on your website, so it gets analyzed by default.

Are you trying to get a "green bar" to present to a client? **Describe the iframe constraints to them.**

Are there too many issues found in the iframe so you can't work with the validation result efficiently? **Use scopes.**